# OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/dev/null' or No IP is showing on my connected network

Tags: python, networking

I am writing a python script which detects IP address connected to my network.

When I run the script in Spyder Anaconda (MAC OS) it runs perfectly.

But when I run the programme in windows it prints only Host IP address, not all the connected IP address.

Also when I run the program via Terminal in MAC OS it again shows me an error of

> OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: '/dev/null'

Any idea what I did wrong?

My code :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Mar 21 09:46:11 2019

@author: vivanksharma
"""

import os
import socket    
import multiprocessing
import subprocess
import os


def pinger(job_q, results_q):
    """
    Do Ping
    :param job_q:
    :param results_q:
    :return:
    """
    DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')
    while True:

        ip = job_q.get()

        if ip is None:
            break

        try:
            subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c1', ip],
                                  stdout=DEVNULL)
            results_q.put(ip)
        except:
            pass
    os.close(os.devnull)


def get_my_ip():
    """
    Find my IP address
    :return:
    """
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    ip = s.getsockname()[0]
    s.close()
    print("Host IP address is "+ip+"\n")
    return ip


def map_network(pool_size=255):
    """
    Maps the network
    :param pool_size: amount of parallel ping processes
    :return: list of valid ip addresses
    """

    ip_list = list()

    # get my IP and compose a base like 192.168.1.xxx
    ip_parts = get_my_ip().split('.')
    base_ip = ip_parts[0] + '.' + ip_parts[1] + '.' + ip_parts[2] + '.'

    # prepare the jobs queue
    jobs = multiprocessing.Queue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    pool = [multiprocessing.Process(target=pinger, args=(jobs, results)) for i in range(pool_size)]

    for p in pool:
        p.start()

    # cue hte ping processes
    for i in range(1, 255):
        jobs.put(base_ip + '{0}'.format(i))

    for p in pool:
        jobs.put(None)

    for p in pool:
        p.join()

    # collect he results
    while not results.empty():
        ip = results.get()
        ip_list.append(ip)

    return ip_list


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print('Mapping...')
    lst = map_network()


    #Define your Friendly IP here

    friendly_ip = ['192.168.43.21']
    for i in lst:
        flag = 0
        for j in friendly_ip:
            if i == j:
                pass
            else:
                flag = 1
        if(flag==1):
            print("Enemy IP is :"+i)



    print("All IP Address connected to network is : "+str(lst))
```

P.S It's not any duplicate question for OSError [Errno 24] I tried them all but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a few things could be going on here. I wasn't able to reproduce your exact error, which makes sense since it's likely linked to your OS's file limit.

1. You have `os.close(os.devnull)`, which I'm pretty sure should be `DEVNULL.close()`. This could mean that you're never closing the file descriptor, leading to "too many open files"
2. You could try running with less concurrency (a smaller `pool_size`). This could make your program slower, but it will at least work. I set it to `2`, and while it took a while, it did eventually finish.